# How to access Mac-specific file metadata?

Tags: python, macos

According to this page, different operating systems can return different information from the os.stat function.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

I am interested in getting the type and creator.

```
import os
from stat import *
print(os.stat('filename').st_ino)
print(os.stat('filename').st_creator)
```

This code works for the inode (st_ino) but gives an error for the creator:

> AttributeError: 'posix.stat_result' object has no attribute 'st_creator'

Same for st_type and st_rsize.

Do I have to do anything special to get these to work?

(This is Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.8 with Python 2. I'm new to Python.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another answer mentions, Mac OS in the documentation means pre-OS X.  In classic Mac OS, `stat` was emulated, whereas Python `stat` actually means `stat` on OS X.

Therefore, you don't get the type and creator with os.stat.  The corresponding low-level call is `getattrlist`, but this isn't wrapped by Python (nor should you really use it).  You can see exactly what is returned by `stat` by printing it:

```
>>> import os
>>> s = os.stat('foo')
>>> s
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33152, st_ino=18294505, st_dev=16777218L, st_nlink=1,
st_uid=501, st_gid=501, st_size=0, st_atime=1379052292, st_mtime=1379052292,
st_ctime=1379052308)
```

Let's set a type and creator on `foo` to test with:

```
% SetFile -t 'TYPE' -c 'CREA' foo
```

The easy answer in Python 2.x is `MacOS.GetCreatorAndType`.  However, it's gone in 3.x and the underlying mechanisms it uses are deprecated.  If your goal is just to get something done for yourself, then by all means use it.

```
>>> import MacOS
>>> MacOS.GetCreatorAndType('foo')
('CREA', 'TYPE')
```

A more future-proof mechanism would be to use PyObjC, which works on Python 3.x and does not use deprecated OS X API:

```
>>> from Foundation import NSFileManager, NSFileHFSCreatorCode, NSFileHFSTypeCode
>>> attributes = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath_error_('foo', None)[0]
>>> attributes[NSFileHFSTypeCode]
1415139397L
>>> attributes[NSFileHFSCreatorCode]
1129465153L
```

These come out as integers because PyObjC has no mapping for four-character codes (nor does it have the appropriate metadata to understand what it's getting).  Here's a quick mapping function to retrieve a four-character string:

```
>>> def decode(f): return ''.join(chr(f >> i * 8 & 0xff) for i in xrange(3,-1,-1))
... 
>>> decode(attributes[NSFileHFSCreatorCode])
'CREA'
>>> decode(attributes[NSFileHFSTypeCode])
'TYPE'
```

(Replace `xrange` with `range` above if you're using Python 3.)

Note that in general, types/creators are not used very much in OS X; their functions have been superseded by file extensions, UTIs, MIME types, per-user and per-document application bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. The background to this project is to convert files from a PPC application running on OS X 10.6. The files *do* actually have Creator and Type codes, and that is how I will identify the files I need to convert as I path.walk() them.

Since this will be running on 10.6, and therefore under Python 2, MacOS.GetCreatorAndType() will be fine. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Disagree with your throwaway remark about `getattrlist()` (“nor should you really use it”).  It’s a documented API.  It is tricky to use correctly, to be fair, but nothing wrong with using it per se.

Comment: The reason not to use getattrlist() is right in the man page: "     The getattrlist() and fgetattrlist() functions are only supported by certain volume format implementations.  For maximum compatibility, client programs should use high-level APIs (such as the Carbon File Manager) to access file system attributes.  These high-level APIs include logic to emulate file system attributes on volumes that don't support the calls."  (Although getattrlist() does seem to understand the AppleDouble files when I tested it on 10.8, so this information may be out of date).  I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

"Mac OS" in the docs here means Mac OS Classic, i.e., before the X. For OSX, the unix and FreeBSD comments are relevant.

Comment: While it's clearly the *worst* answer, I thought it would be enough to explain to asker that they were misreading the docs, and that they shouldn't expect them to work.

Comment: I wrote the big long answer and upvoted this one :-)  I think it's a good point; I had no idea where he got `st_creator` from and didn't think to look in the documentation.

Comment: Interesting. My misunderstanding came about because so often, even 10 years after OS9 was superseded by OS X, OS X is described all over the place using the term "Mac OS". Even teh Python documentation is a bit ambiguous. This page:

Comment: (continued...) This page uses the term "Mac OS 9" to refer explicitly to the earlier operating system, and "Mac OS X" to refer to the current operating system:

http://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html#using-on-mac

So perhaps I could be forgiven for assuming "Mac OS" was generic referring to both. :-)

Comment: Hm, sounds like it's a documentation bug or I didn't interpret it correctly.

Comment: It is definitely a documentation bug because OS 9 support was removed from Python after 2.3.

Comment: Is this about OS9 or is it Carbon? Carbon is still supported afaik, although deprecated.

Comment: This refers much more to the OS 9-specific Python implementation than anything else (with the emulated `stat`).  The `MacOS.GetCreatorAndType()` I describe above does use Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

You can check

```
print(dir(os.stat('filename')))
```

to see which attributes are available on your system.
Unfortunately Mac OS **X** does not return username of file owner, so you will need something like `pwd` to "translate" user ID to username.

```
import os
import pwd

uid = os.stat('filename').st_uid
owner = pwd.getpwuid(uid)
print(owner)
print(owner.pw_name)
```